# reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement

Problem desc: The university bookstore has a Kilobyte Day sale every October 24, giving an 8 percent discount on all computer accessory purchases if the price is less than $128, and a 16 percent discount if the price is at least $128. Write a program that asks the cashier for the original price and then prints the discounted price.

I am trying to solve this problem. and I am getting errors in line #24.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    double original_price;
    double discount_rate;
    double discount_price;

    cout << "Enter Original Price:" << endl;

    cin >> original_price;

    //cout << original_price << endl;

    if (original_price < 128)
    {
        discount_rate = 0.92;
    }
    else
    {
        discount_rate = 0.84;
    }
    double discounted_price = discount_rate * original_price << endl;
    cout << "discounted_price: " << discounted_price;

    return 0;
}
```

error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?

Comment: The title is there to summarize your problem, not state that you're having a problem.

Comment: If you're asking about an error, please provide the compiler / program output.  Don't require your readers to guess.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following line is not well-formed:

```
double discounted_price = discount_rate * original_price<<endl;
```

`std::endl` is used with `std::cout` to end a line and flush the output. You can only really invoke `operator<<(std::endl)` on an output stream, not on a `double`. In fact, there is no real meaning to trying to attach an end-of-line to a numerical value in this way.

Do the following instead:

```
double discounted_price = discount_rate * original_price;
cout << "discounted_price: "<< discounted_price << endl;
```

This computes the discounted price, and then prints it with `std::endl` used to add a newline and flush the standard output stream.

Answer (score 2):

Much better but you are still putting `endl` in the wrong place.

```
double discounted_price = discount_rate * original_price<<endl;
cout << "discounted_price: "<< discounted_price;
```

should be

```
double discounted_price = discount_rate * original_price;
cout << "discounted_price: "<< discounted_price << endl;
```

`endl` is an output operation, its used to add a newline to your output, it has no place when you are doing calculations.

Comment: `endl` is function, thus the unresolved function type in error.

Comment: `endl` adds a newline **and a flush**. Inserting `’\n’` starts a new line.